# Connection to MySQL database does not work

Tags: pi-3, connection, ethernet-port, mysql, mariadb

I have two **Raspbery PI 3** which I have installed (almost) identical.
The configuration of /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf is identical for both Raspberrys.

**Problem:** I can only connect to the mysql database of **one of these** Raspberrys (using `MySQL Workbench`). So I looked for the problem and found a more "low level" problem: even telnet is not working on one of these Raspberrys.

> telnet raspberry1 3306

works perfect, while

> telnet raspberry2 3306

tells me that a connection cannot be established.

A ping works from my windows pc to both raspberrys.
A local connection to the MySQL server also works on both Raspberrys.

I even tried to disable any firewall on raspberry2 using `sudo /sbin/iptables --flush`

When using a port scanner like `sudo nmap -sS -O raspberry1 raspberry2` I see that port 3306 is open on raspberry1 but not on raspberry2.

`sudo netstat -ln` gives me a slightly different output on both RPi's:

```
raspberry1:
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
raspberry2:
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned above the file `50-server.cnf` is identical on both raspberries - especially the line `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` is set in both files.
(I also restarted raspberry2 using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`. I even restarted Raspbian.)
I still have no clue where the Local Address 127.0.0.1 comes from.

Where could be differences in the configuration of the second Raspberry Pi?

Comment: how are you running the telnet commands?

Comment: @jsotola: On a windows computer I entered the commandline (cmd) and sent the commands ("telnet raspberry2 3306")

Comment: @Fabian: I try to connect to the database using the program "MySQL Workbench". But this can't work as long as telnet isn't able to get a connection. With my question I ask for ideas, which differences between both Raspberrys could cause this problem.

Comment: Any firewalls in the mix, either on the network or on the server?  Might they be doing an IP whitelist or similar?

Comment: @Paul: I tried to disable firewall temporarily using 'sudo /sbin/iptables --flush'. My Fritz Box doesn't have any white-/black-listing of specific ip adresses configured as far as I know.

Comment: @Fabian: Which necessary details could I post more? I answered on every comment here and added specific information about each idea which came up in the comments. I'm quite desperate about my problem and look for a solution.

Comment: please run on both RPis `sudo netstat -ln | grep 3306` and post the result

Comment: @Fabian: I added the result of `netstat -ln` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, the MariaDB server listens for TCP/IP connections on a network socket bound to a single address [...] In Debian [...] the default bind_address is 127.0.0.1, which binds the server to listen on localhost only.

source: [Server System Variables - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#bind_address)

`sudo netstat -ln` shows in the column "Local Address" for your raspberry1 "0.0.0.0:3306" (all IPv4s are allowed to access this device on port 3306) and for your raspberry2 "127.0.0.1:3306" (only localhost is allowed):

```
raspberry1:
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
raspberry2:
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

This is the reason why you can connect to raspberry1 on port 3306, but not to raspberry2 on the same port. To make your raspberry2 accessible just set the correct [bind_address](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#bind_address) in [mycnf](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/).

Security advice: If your RPis are not behind a well managed firewall, please read [why it is a bad idea to allow direct connections to your databases](https://serverfault.com/q/283172) and [how you can configure MariaDB in a safe way for remote client access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/).

Comment: Both files `50-server.cfg` already contain `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and I restarted the mysql server (and even the whole operating system). I still get the Local Address `127.0.0.1`. Do you know if there is any way how the setting in the config file may be overwritten (e. g. by command line param)? My problem still exists :-(

Comment: @MichaelHutter for testing purposes set the bind_address at 50-server.cfg to a different IPv4 from you network, i.e. 192.168.178.1 and restart. Then run again netstat and let me know the result (maybe you've edited the wrong config file).

Comment: I found my mistake. I had a second (backup) file with extension .cnf in the folder `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d`. This file was additionally executed after my real .cnf file. Now with your answer I am able to connect to the database. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelHutter Glad to hear it's solved! Cheers!